# How do I get the Suggested Sentence in a string as output in LanguageTool?

Tags: java, languagetool

I am using LanguageTool along with Eclipse. The API can be accessed using the link: [Click here](http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api). I am able to get the text output from it which shows that certain columns have misspelled words but I am not able to get the output which is the corrected string version of the misspelled string given as the input. Here is my code:

```
JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check("A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy");

for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
  System.out.println("Potential error at line " +
      match.getLine() + ", column " +
      match.getColumn() + ": " + match.getMessage());
  System.out.println("Suggested correction: " +
      match.getSuggestedReplacements());
}
```

The output obtained is:

```
Potential error at line 0, column 17: Use <suggestion>an</suggestion> instead of 'a' if the following word starts with a vowel sound, e.g. 'an article', 'an hour'
Suggested correction: [an]
Potential error at line 0, column 32: Possible spelling mistake found
Suggested correction: [Hitch-hiker]
Potential error at line 0, column 51: Did you mean <suggestion>to the</suggestion>?
Suggested correction: [to the]
```

I would like the output to be the corrected version of the input string as:

```
A sentence with an error in the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
```

How do I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with using `getFromPos()`, `getToPos()` methods:

```
private static final String TEST_SENTENCE = "A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StringBuffer correctSentence = new StringBuffer(TEST_SENTENCE);

    JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
    List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check(TEST_SENTENCE);

    int offset = 0;
    for (RuleMatch match : matches) {

        correctSentence.replace(match.getFromPos() - offset, match.getToPos() - offset, match.getSuggestedReplacements().get(0));
        offset += (match.getToPos() - match.getFromPos() - match.getSuggestedReplacements().get(0).length());

    }

    System.out.println(correctSentence.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of `match.getSuggestedReplacements()` and replace the original input string with that from `match.getFromPos()` to `match.getToPos()`. Which one of the suggestions to use (if there's more than one) cannot be determined automatically, the user has to select one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information. I will try that. So, there isn't any direct statements to perform it, right? Through string manipulation itself?

Comment: @Ravichandra No, direct decision to perform this task exist. Look at my answer.