# Iterate through corrected words

Tags: java, languagetool

having in mind [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675624/how-do-i-get-the-suggested-sentence-in-a-string-as-output-in-languagetool)

how can we not only extract the first element from the correction match, but extract the whole list and store it into the StringBuffer[].

I want to do that in order to be able then to compare every element of this corrected list with a user input and use whichever element matches the list.

So, for example, user enters: `Sain Nicolaa`.

The corrected words are:

```
[main, said, San, gain, skin, Spain, pain, rain, spin, sail, saint, slain, vain, Cain, Jain, stain, satin, shin, Sabin, ain, fain, swain, sin, lain, wain, s ain]
```

and

```
 [Nicolas, Nicola]
```

So, I want to compare my input to each one of these corrected words and use whatever it matches.

We will need a second loop on the match:

```
for (RuleMatch match : matches) {

    correctSentence.replace(match.getFromPos() - offset, match.getToPos() - offset, match.getSuggestedReplacements().get(0));
    offset += (match.getToPos() - match.getFromPos() - match.getSuggestedReplacements().get(0).length());

}
```

but I am not sure how to handle this, what kind of type must be.

Comment: Why use a StringBuffer ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard:I was just using the example from the question.I guess I can use an ArrayList<String>?